# How can I get a count of percent negative and order by most negative?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I figured out a way to do a group by and get counts based on two fields:

```
df.groupby(['brand','result']).size()
df.groupby(['brand','result']).count()
```

This yields the same results.  My data now looks like this.

```
Johnson's Baby Powder   negative         21  
                        neutral          5  
                        positive         121

Estee Lauder            negative         7  
                        positive         23

Calvin Klein            negative         10  
                        neutral          3  
                        positive         29
```

I would like to get the percentage of result for each brand, like this.

```
Johnson's Baby Powder   negative    21  0.142857143
                        neutral     5   0.034013605
                        positive    121 0.823129252

Estee Lauder            negative    7   0.233333333
                        positive    23  0.766666667

Calvin Klein            negative    10  0.238095238
                        neutral     3   0.071428571
                        positive    29  0.69047619
```

Ultimately, though, I want to show only the 'brand' that has 'result' with negative > 20%.

So, I want to see this (and other brands that meet the business logic rules).

```
Estee Lauder            negative    7   0.233333333
                        positive    23  0.766666667
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
x = df.groupby(['brand'])['result'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Sample data output

```
>>> y = x.loc[(x.index.get_level_values(1) == 'negative')]

>>> y[y>0.2]
airline         airline_sentiment
American        negative             0.710402
Delta           negative             0.429793
Southwest       negative             0.490083
US Airways      negative             0.776862
United          negative             0.688906
Virgin America  negative             0.359127
Name: airline_sentiment, dtype: float64

>>> y[y>0.2].index.get_level_values(0)
Index(['American', 'Delta', 'Southwest', 'US Airways', 'United',
       'Virgin America'],
      dtype='object', name='airline')
```

Comment: Sweet!!  That gives me the % for each.  How can I show only brands that have >20% negative.  Maybe I have to put it into a dataframe and then apply a filter.  Is that the way to go with this?  TY.

Comment: Could you add some sample data @ASH

Comment: So, using your code, I can see this:

Polo positive 0.783237
 negative 0.210983
 neutral 0.00578
Proactiv positive 0.677419
 negative 0.322581
Pure positive 0.709524
 negative 0.271429
 neutral 0.019048
Olay positive 0.803497
 negative 0.174854
 neutral 0.021649

I don't want to see Olay because the negative percent calculation is <20%.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Vishnudev's answer, use:

```
print(df[df.groupby(['brand'])['result'].value_counts(normalize=True).ge(0.5).tolist()])
```

Output:

```
          brand    result  number
3  Estee Lauder  negative       7
4  Estee Lauder  positive      23
```

Comment: This looks promising, FowardVickel.  However, when I run your code, I get this error: IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 443 instead of 35907

Comment: @ASH Edited try now